# How to covert a character string into a list variable in R?

Tags: r, string, list, variable-assignment, string-conversion

I would like to convert a character string into a variable name for a list variable, Here is an example.

```
   x=rnorm(1:100)
   y=rnorm(1:100)*5+10
   OneDimModel = NULL; 
   OneDimModel$model =  lm(y~x)
```

I would like to reassign list variable **`OneDimModel`** for one individual case to a summarising variable `paste("DataCentre$sitenumber", i, sep="")`, where **`[i]`** can be varied across different cases.

So the end product would be something like for case 1:

```
  DataCentre$sitenumber1 = OneDimModel
```

I have tried function `assign()`, but it only works for single value, could someone help me.

Comment: I don't follow.  Do you want a nested list called `DataCentre`?

Comment: Yes but with a designated name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do use extract operator `[[`

```
text.index <- paste("sitenumber", i, sep="")
DataCentre[[text.index]] <- OneDimModel
```

Or simply

```
DataCentre[[paste("sitenumber", i, sep="")]] <- OneDimModel
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worded.